# Spring configuration: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I think that something is missing in the configuration files, but I can not see.

When I put in the browser --> localhost:8080/Procura/notifications --> I get in the console this --> 
**org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Warnung: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Procura/notifications] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'**

Web.xml (I tried with 3.0 too)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Procura</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

application-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/procura</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>procura</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>procura</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.procura.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.procura.service"/>

</beans>
```

mvc-config.xml (I tried too with`<mvc:default-servlet-handler />`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.procura.controller" />

</beans>
```

Controller

```
package com.procura.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class NotificationController {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/notifications")
    public String listAll(Model uiModel) {
        System.out.println("In method");
        logger.info("Listing notifications");
        return "notifications/list";
    }
}
```

Project structure

[image]

Comment: don't you have errors, warning during server startup ?

Comment: @FredericClose --> When I put in the browser --> localhost:8080/Procura/notifications --> I get in the console this --> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound Warnung: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Procura/notifications] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'. But the server startup is correct

Comment: yes, but what about server startup, or when your application is deployed ?

Comment: When I startup the server all is correct, and the same about the deployment

Comment: try changing `context:component-scan` to this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.procura" />`

Comment: @DebojitSaikia I changed in both spring xml, and I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Tomcat was corrupted. But now all work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />` is conflicting with @RequestMapping annotations.
If you want to use annotated request mapping to map your request url to controller, try removing BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping from your spring mvc config

Comment: I don´t know if there is any conflict but if I remove this line from the xml, I get the same error.

Comment: can you please enable debug logs for spring and provide the logs ? Also can you confirm how you deploying your app, if its a war is the war name Procura.war ?

Answer (score 0):

The first even let the dispatcherServlet block with the suffix such as: *.do;
So that the jsp suffix will not be blocked,The second method is to add in spring-servlet.xml
mvc:default-servlet-handler